Some passed fields in the users.profile.set method in Slack API are not modified
To test the functionality I created an application on https://api.slack.com/apps, in OAuth & Permissions I specified users.profile:write in User Token Scopes.
Next, I tried to use the API method users.profile.set to change real_name, title and custom field information with the Role description information. I tried to send request, the real_name field changes as I expected, however the title and custom field does not change. The code of my request:
curl --location 'https://slack.com/api/users.profile.set' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
  "user": "${USER_ID}",
  "profile": {
        "real_name": "John Doe",
        "title": "Full Stack",
        "fields": {
            "Xf07SB7V91F1": {
                "value": "Full Stack",
                "alt": ""
            }
        }
    }
}'

I get this response:
{
    "ok": true,
    "profile": {
        "title": "Test title",
        "real_name": "John Doe",
        "real_name_normalized": "John Doe",
        "display_name": "John Doe",
        "display_name_normalized": "John Doe",
        "fields": {
            "Xf07SB7V91F1": {
                "value": "Front",
                "alt": ""
            }
        }
     }
}

What could be the problem if the real_name field changes, however the custom fields and title does not change after submitting the request?
